# $\sum_{q=1}^{u}(n+qd)^m\equiv n^mu(\mod d) $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Observing the pattern I claimed that,

**Problem**

Show that $$\sum_{q=1}^{u}(n+qd)^m\equiv n^mu(\mod d)  $$

$\forall n,u,m,d\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Just replace $qd$ by $0$ ?

Comment: Note $u\ge q \ge 1$ and $d\ge 1$ so we can't replace .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First prove this result
$$a\equiv b\pmod{d} \Rightarrow a^m\equiv b^m\pmod{d}$$
Then since $n+qd\equiv n\pmod{d}$ you have $(n+qd)^m\equiv n^m\pmod{d}$.